How to match RF transmitter (EV1527) and receiver (SYN470) together?
I have a transmitter that uses EV1527 encoder IC in 433 MHz. Here I want to make a receiver by SYN470. In this case, I am amateur and I do not know how to match transmitter and receiver together in a way that other 433 MHz signals do not affect it.
Another question is how can I make my receiver learning code by push button to add other transmitters if I want, as I have seen in many receiver modules that they have button for this purpose.
Do I need to have a microcontroller beside my receiver or not? In some devices there is microcontroller and in some there is not.



OOK is not particularly viable on 433MHz since it's a public band in many countries with lots of disturbances. And for the same reason it isn't viable to have broad modulation. In practice, narrowband FSK is the only thing that will work reliably on the band.
